# Python AssertionError: on boolean value

Tags: dockerfile, python-3.10

In my python code that I use to build my app docker image I'm trying to ensure that the variable CHECKDNS are always set explicitly to either False or True:

```
self.dnscheck: bool = (os.environ.get("CHECKDNS") or remote_config_data.get("CHECKDNS"))
if not self.dnscheck:
   raise CheckDnsUndefined()
```

Below are code snippets I use to set up some test to ensure sane configs:

```
MOCK_GOOD_CONFIG_JSON = """{
    "TESTURL": "http://www.google.com",
    "CHECKDNS": true,
    "TESTRUN": false
}"""
......

MOCK_GOOD_CONFIG = json.loads(MOCK_GOOD_CONFIG_JSON)

     self.checkdns: bool = (os.environ.get("CHECKDNS") or remote_config_data.get("CHECKDNS"))
        if not self.checkdns:
            raise CheckDnsUndefined()
......

class TestConfig:

    @classmethod
    def set_env_vars(cls):
        for key, value in MOCK_GOOD_CONFIG.items():
            env_var = key.upper()
            os.environ[env_var] = (' '.join(value) if type(value) == list
                                   else str(value))

    @classmethod
    def check_config(cls, config: Config):
        for key, value in MOCK_GOOD_CONFIG.items():
            key = key.lower()  
            assert getattr(config, key) == value, f"Wrong {key} value in config"

.......

    @mock.patch('service_monitor.config.Config._fetch_remote_config', side_effect=[MOCK_GOOD_CONFIG])
    def test_constructor_good_config_from_env(self, mock_fetch_remote_config):
        self.set_env_vars()
        self.check_config(Config())
```

However I'm getting some errors to do with assertion during the build:

```
22:30:10  >               assert getattr(config, key) == value, f"Wrong {key} value in config"
22:30:10  E               AssertionError: Wrong checkdns value in config
22:30:10  E               assert 'True' == True
22:30:10  E                +  where 'True' = getattr(<service_monitor.config.Config object at 0x7f54b14291e0>, 'checkdns')
```

I'm assuming that its having issues asserting boolean values and I'm sure I'm doing this the wrong way...any ideas how I can amend my code so the error goes away and I can ensure the CHECKDNS variable is always set (either to False or True) in the config (if not set, then it raises exception).

Thanks muchly

Sidenote - I've tried changing `assert getattr(config, key) == value, f"Wrong {key} value in config"` to `assert bool(getattr(config, key)) == value, f"Wrong {key} value in config"` - this is wrong apparently and I've also tried changing bool to str with no success